# How to ideas - Type tester, input type in div?

Tags: html, types

First post here, looking for suggestions how I might achieve something.

I have a few symbol fonts I've designed that I would like to display online.

I'd like a type testing area where you use the font.

I think I might be able to do this with php and the GD library - Type something
into a text box then use php to create and image.

What I'd really like is something like this.

http://www.mckltype.com/retail/

You can type straight into the text and it's displayed live.

I thought this might be done with an input text field but the code for this page just has a div.

Any ideas on how I might achieve something like this.

I'm not looking to copy this just ideas on how I can type on a page in a font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at that page source, you'll see that those elements have `contenteditable="true"`, which makes them editable.

You could also just make an `<input type="text" />` and use CSS to change the font and hide the border.